# How to calculate execution time and memory usage of java program using console?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, time, command-line-arguments

I have made a Java program similar to the code below :

```
class class1{
    public static void main(String []args){
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            class2 c2 = new class2();
            c2.start();
        }
    }
}
class class2 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        // do some long job here
    }
}
```

This program uses threads which runs for significant amount of time. I want to analyze the time taken and memory consumed by the program in order to further optimize it. But the classical approach to calculate time like this one does not do the required job :

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

doReallyLongThing();

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Time taken : " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
```

Because the class1 finishes the job before the threads finish their jobs. So I want a command line solution to get the execution time. Something like using flags as command line arguments. Also the same for memory calculation. I found that **jconsole** command is helpful to analyze various aspects of java program but it opens in separate terminal and is not so good for the purpose I am looking for.

Comment: The `main` method in `class1` only finishes before the threads because you don't wait for them to complete, which is easily done by calling [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) on all of them in a second loop.

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, i.e. `Class1` and `Class2`.